# translating phrases into propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

translate the following into propositional logic:

```
students attend the annual meetings
```

where s: students

A: attend annual meetings

my first intuition is:

s -> A
however there is no "if, then" relationship in the sentence. any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure 'A' isn't "attends annual meetings"?

Comment: yes sorry just updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in propositional logic, each letter symbols (i.e. **A** and **s**) should stand for a whole sentence. Notice how **s**, in your question above, is not an entire sentence. This should be a clue as to what you need to do to solve the problem. You should change your definition of **s** to a sentence.

How do you go about doing this? Notice that the sentence "Students attend the annual meetings" is a statement about students in general. Therefore, you should think "If a person is a student, then they do **A**". Notice that even though this sentence is not in **if-then** form, it is clear that it is making a statement equivalent to the one I have written above.

Long story short; you should change **s** to a sentence, but otherwise, your intuition is correct.